# Detect Text Fields with CNN and convert it to feature array

Tags: python, keras, ocr, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to detect mostly text fields (not OCR, i.e, my goal is not to detect what is written but areas where is written some text). Some images may be important as well (but not much)

For example:
[image: new example]

The output must be an feature array.
I had an *VGG19* from keras working, but the results aren't awesome because i think it isn't trained to deal with text fields or documents.

```
img = image.load_img(imagepath, target_size=(224, 224))
img_data = image.img_to_array(img)
img_data = np.expand_dims(img_data, axis=0)
img_data = preprocess_input(img_data)
features = model.predict(img_data)
features = np.array(features)   - expected output
```

Is there any CNN already trained to do this? If not, what approach do you suggest?

Comment: i dont want to post this as an answer because its just a link but https://www.learnopencv.com/deep-learning-based-text-detection-using-opencv-c-python/ is very good. there is a white paper linked on "EAST: An Efficient and Accurate Scene Text Detector".

the article continues into using Tesseract for OCR but EAST sounds exactly like what you are looking for

Comment: `keras-ocr` might be what you're looking for. See here: https://pypi.org/project/keras-ocr/

Comment: I want text fields, not exactly OCR

Comment: i edited the example